# jquery select an element with inner element

Tags: jquery

> `<li>`

tag. I want to select one of them, with using href property of  tag inside of them.

I tried something like,

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[href^='Default.aspx']").parents
            .removeclass("menu")
            .addClass("menuac");

        });
```

this but that didn't work :(.

note that I am trying to reach my

> `<li>`

tag.

html part is like this:

```
   <ul>
    <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Read.aspx">Read</a></li>
    <li><a href="Archive.aspx">Archive</a></li>
   </ul>
```

thanks..

Comment: `.parents` ? Do you want `.parents()` ?

Comment: yeah, :) 4-5 instant answers. but I think the problem is NOT at the  selecting part. I think When I try to remove the class menu, I dont remove the menu:hover one. Can u help at this point?

Comment: No, we don't have enough information here. Please build a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com).

Comment: It s not that hard I think. I have a class with :hover attribute.
And I try to remove that class with :hover attribute of course. (using .removeClass function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `:has()` selector to accomplish your task elegantly,

```
$("li:has(a[href^='Default.aspx'])").removeclass("menu").addClass("menuac");
```

---

```js
$("li:has(a[href^='Default.aspx'])").addClass("menuac");
```

```css
.menuac {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Read.aspx">Read</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Archive.aspx">Archive</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: master, here is another question: if I remove the menu class above, do I also remove the menu:hover at the same time? (with .removeClass function of course)

Comment: @MuhammedCAKMAK Yes, because that hover functionality is being tightly coupled with that class. So obviously that would also be gone.

Comment: @MuhammedCAKMAK Glad to help.! And by the way, if you feel anyone of the provided answers here has satisfied your need, then try to click on the tick mark available with that answer to show your acceptance to the future visitors of this question. And This is not a compulsion...

Comment: oh yeah, I tried instantly to click your tick but it said 6mins needed. Good to remind me.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$("a[href^='Default.aspx']").parents
```

you probably wanted

```
$("a[href^='Default.aspx']").parents()
```

but a better solution, if I guess correctly your goal, would be

```
$("a[href^='Default.aspx']").closest('li')
```

Comment: yeah, that was a mistake too. But I still couldnt select my li tag :(

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[href^='Default.aspx']").parents()
        .removeclass("menu")
        .addClass("menuac");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$("a[href^='Default.aspx']").parent().removeclass("menu").addClass("menuac");
```

or

```
$("a[href^='Default.aspx']").parents(":eq(0)").removeclass("menu").addClass("menuac");
```